# Make element transparent except border?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make an entire element invisible *except* for its border or outline using pure CSS? By "invisible", I mean entirely transparent (i.e. `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;`) with a visible surrounding border. All text, children, background, et al., would be hidden.

I know this could be accomplished by creating a parent `div` around the invisible element, but I am curious as to whether or not it would be possible to achieve the same effect without changing the HTML.

Can this be done?

Comment: border is inherently tied to the element's opacity and visibility. is the intention that you want to be able to 'click through' the element to content underneath while maintaining a border?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @APAD1 —while this is mostly a conceptual question, what I was envisioning in my head was a placeholder block for a drag and drop interface. I am wondering if CSS changes are sufficient, or if extra work would need to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think it is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="element">
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#element * {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This should work as long as everything within the containing element is wrapped in another element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that using child selections.

[Example](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/DpcFr)

```
<div class="box">
  <p>some child content</p>
</div>

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:5px solid black;

}
.box >* {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RGBA as color to achieve that, have a look at this:

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uuo0su1f/)

THE STYLE:

```
body {
  background: red;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

div * {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

THE MARKUP:

```
<div>
    <span>Guten Morgen</span>
</div>
```